# Save output of a script in txt (Windows)

Tags: python, scripting

I created a script to see all the files in a folder and print the full path of each file.
The script is working and prints the output in the Command Prompt (Windows)

```
import os

root = 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Folder'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print os.path.join(path, name)
```

I want now to save the output in a txt file so I have edited the code assigning the `os.path.join(path,name)` to a variable `values` but, when I print the output, the script gives me an error

```
import os

root = 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Folder'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        values = os.path.join(path, name)

file = open('sample.txt', 'w')
file.write(values)
file.close()
```

Error below

```
file.write(values)
NameError: name 'values' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the variable `values` is only limited to the scope of the inner for loop. So assign empty value to the variable before you start the iteration. Like `values=None` or better yet `values=''` Now assuming the above code even worked you wouldn't get the output file you desired. You see, the variable values is being regularly updated. So after the iteration the location of the last file encountered would be stored in values which would then be written in the `sample.txt` file.

Another bad practice you seem to be following is using `\` instead of `\\` inside strings. This might come to bite you later (if they haven't already). You see `\` when followed by a letter denotes an escape sequence\character and `\\` is the escape sequence for slash.

So here's a redesigned working sample code:

```
import os
root = 'C:\\Users\\marco\\Desktop\\Folder'
values=''

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        values = values + os.path.join(path, name) + '\n'

samplef = open('sample.txt', 'w')
samplef.write(values)
samplef.close()
```

In case you aren't familiar, `'\n'` denotes the escape sequence for a new-line. Reading your output file would be quite tedious had all your files been written been on the same line.

PS: I did the code with stings as that's what I would prefer in this scenario, but you way try arrays or lists or what-not. Just be sure that you define the variable beforehand lest you should get out of scope.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
file = open('sample.txt', 'w')
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        values = os.path.join(path, name)
        file.write(values+'\n')
file.close()
```

Note that `file` is a builtin symbol in Python (which is overridden here), so I suggest that you replace it with `fileDesc` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

import os

```
root = 'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\Folder'
file = open('sample.txt', 'w')
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
       values = os.path.join(path, name)
       file.write(values)
file.close()
```

values is not defined to be availbale in the lexical scope of the file. It is scoped within a inner loop. change it as above, will work.